# Doctrine 2.2/ORM trouble : Entity/table replicated for each PostgreSQL schema

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, postgresql-9.1

When using Doctrine 2.2 & PostgreSQL (under Symfony 2.1, but it has nothing to do with it) one declare an entity as follows:

```
<doctrine-mapping ...>
  <entity name="User" table="**clientschema**.*User*">
  </entity>
</doctrine-mapping>
```

My database hosts as many *User* tables as there are **clientschema** schemas like this (which separates data from one client to another & is clean practice IMO) :

- client1.User
- client2.User
- ...

So, basically, for each new client I replicate User table under a new dedicated schema. Of course, I also replicate all other necessary tables under new client schema.

And here comes trouble, when declaring my *User* entity I can't actually set a schema name in table field because there are many possible! Actually, it depends on which client is connected to the application...

Do you guys have any workaround? Can we set the table field dynamically for each entity (including correct schema)? Maybe another ORM that deals better with PostgreSQL schemas?